# Django forms - form field for each model

Tags: python, django, forms

I am stuck with a problem - I want to add a simple form field to edit the objects that I am looping through in the template. Here's my model:

```
class Topic(BaseModel):
name = models.TextField()
```

Here's my model form:

```
class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Topic
    fields = ["name"]
```

And here's my views:

```
def App(request):
    tname = Topic.objects.get(pk=1)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TopicForm(data = request.POST, instance=tname)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

And my template is simple:

```
{% for lecture in lectures %}
<form action="/app/" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="Post">
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

The thing is that I want to have a form field to edit EACH model not just one that has a pk of 1... how do I do that ?

Comment: You should fix your indentation

Comment: The indentation is fine, I just messed it up in this post.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do `objects.all()` instead of `get(pk=1)`.  Then loop over those objects, and save them to a list that you save to the context.  Something like this:

```
tnames = Topic.objects.all()
lectures = []
for tname in tnames:
  lectures.append(TopicForm(instance=tname))

context = { 
  'lectures' : lectures
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. You saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

More specifically, you probably want to look into Model formsets. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset. Then you can directly give a queryset as initial data.

Comment: Hello. Sorry that I am answering just now.. But is there a way to add additional data when looping over model formset's forms ? Because I am  listing my objects in a for loop and model formset also uses for loop.. The thing that I am trying to achieve is to list all of my objects using a for loop and add a form to each of them to edit it. It seems so simple. The number of objects is unknown and user will be able to add them dynamically.